# Pritunl setup with Amazon Documentdb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I'm setting up pritunl and I want to use Amazon Document DB instead Mongo DB or Mongo DB Atlas. This is for a vpn idea that I had, server is running ubuntu 18.04 and followed the standard install guide from pritunl, I have it working correctly with MongoDB but for DR and scaling purposes I owuld like to get this into the AWS Document DB.

I have modified the /etc/pritunl.conf file and replaced the default local mongodb_uri with the document DR URI. restarted the service and I would exspect to see the pritunl login/setup page there.  I have opened the retired ports on the box and run thought the pritunl setup page and it just hangs

```
 "mongodb_uri": null,
    "log_path": "/var/log/pritunl.log",
    "static_cache": true,
    "temp_path": "/tmp/pritunl_de511dc19aaf497dbdf67df0a0634e3d",
    "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "www_path": "/usr/share/pritunl/www",
    "local_address_interface": "auto",
    "port": 443
```

```
 "mongodb_uri": mongodb://user:<***************>@vpn-pritunlleu-west-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/test,
    "log_path": "/var/log/pritunl.log",
    "static_cache": true,
    "temp_path": "/tmp/pritunl_de511dc19aaf497dbdf67df0a0634e3d",
    "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "www_path": "/usr/share/pritunl/www",
    "local_address_interface": "auto",
    "port": 443
```

Answer (score 2):

turns out that DocumentDB does not support  tailable cursors or capped collections which is a fundamental requirement for pritunl so going to used MongoDB Atlas or something like that.

Comment: did this change with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html - going to try this out

Comment: @VincentDeSmet what did your tests show? Do the new changes make DocumentDB viable?

Comment: Still not got capped collections. Install fails for me.

Comment: still the same - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Answer (score 0):

A hanging connection is typically a result of the client not being able to connect to the DocumentDB cluster because the cluster's security group does not allow inbound connections on 27017 or the client is in a different VPC as the cluster.

For troubleshooting, please see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting.cannot-connect